# Testing angular component form for pristine is not working

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have a form that has an input and I have a button that needs to be enabled only when the form data was changed. I am using a pristine check and it all works functionally in the browser but I am having trouble to test it. No matter what I do the pristine check is always true no matter how many times I set the values. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The HTML has 2 inputs with labels and a button

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()"
      [formGroup]="form">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" formControlName="email" name="email">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" formControlName="password">
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

My typescript file

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

export class User {
  constructor(public email: string,
              public password: string) {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-component',
  templateUrl: './login-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-component.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() loggedIn = new EventEmitter<User>();
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    });
  }

  login() {
    console.log(`Login ${this.form.value}`);
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.loggedIn.emit(
        new User(
          this.form.value.email,
          this.form.value.password
        )
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And the 2 tests. I have tried with asych testing and without. I also tried setting the value of the native element and on the form. But in both cases the pristine check is always true. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {LoginComponentComponent} from './login-component.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";

describe('Component: Login', () => {

  let component: LoginComponentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponentComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
      declarations: [LoginComponentComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
  });

  it('Tried WIHTOUT async function', () => {
    expect(component.form.pristine).toBeTrue();         //Should not be in a modified state when it starts
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="email"]')).nativeElement;
    //Try to set the control itself and the form
    component.form.controls.email.setValue("2")
    inputElement.value = '2';

    //Detect changes and wait to be stable
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputElement.value).toEqual("2");  //Test that the value has infact change
    expect(component.form.pristine).toBeFalse();   //This fails
  });

  it('Tried using async function', async(() => {
    expect(component.form.pristine).toBeTrue();         //Should not be in a modified state when it starts
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="email"]')).nativeElement;
    //Try to set the control itself and the form
    component.form.controls.email.setValue("2")
    inputElement.value = '2';

    //Detect changes and wait to be stable
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(inputElement.value).toEqual("2");  //Test that the value has infact change
      expect(component.form.pristine).toBeFalse(); //This fails
    });
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not working because

> A control is pristine if the user has not yet changed the value in the UI.

Only if you change value using UI, the pristine property will become false.
Setting/changing form values programmatically doesn't change it.

One way to fix this is, in your tests you can use `component.form.markAsDirty()` to make pristine false and make the tests work properly.

[Read more here.](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl)

Other way is to simulate the behaviour as if value was changed from UI, you can use

```
component.form.controls.email.setValue("2");
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Or

```
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
inputElement.value = '2';
```

Comment: Hi Ashish,Thanks so far that has been the best way to get my tests to pass. 

But is there no way to use the "UI" to change values in a test?

Comment: You can use this to simulate that`inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`

Comment: Why do you dispattch the event before setting value?  I thought you'd set value and then do dispatch